# How to split a pandas dataframe that contains lists as fields into a multi-indexed dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a pandas Dataframe that contains lists as elements(not numpy arrays) and would like to break it up into a hierarchically indexed Dataframe. 
Here is an example of what I am trying to achive:
I have a DataFrame of this form:

```
 | Model  | Company  | Url  | Criteria              |    Rating
1| Mode11 | Company1 | Url1 |[Criteria1, Criteria2] | [Rating1 , Rating2]     
2| Mode12 | Company2 | Url2 |[Criteria4, Criteria5] | [Rating4, Rating5]
```

Into

```
               |Model | Company |  Url  | Rating
               ----------------------------------
     Criteria 1|Model1| Company1| Url1  |Rating1
     Criteria 2|Model1| Company1| Url1  |Rating2
     Criteria 3|Model1| Company1| Url1  |Rating3
     Criteria 4|Model2| Company2| Url2  |Rating4
     Criteria 5|Model2| Company2| Url2  |Rating5
     Criteria 6|Model2| Company2| Url2  |Rating6
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the `Criteria` and `Rating` columns?  Which one are you trying to index by, or is it both?  To clarify, why do the `Rating` elements get split up in your desired result?

Comment: Are the Criteria and Rating lists always the same length and in the same order, or do you need to parse the names to figure out which matches which?

Comment: Criteria and Rating are always of the same length and order. [where each criteria has a one-to-one relationship with the rating]

Comment: @offbyone sorry forgot to notify you of my comment

Comment: @cphlewis also [newbie problems]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys # you don't need StringIO if you're reading the data from a file
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO 
import pandas as pd


dfstr = StringIO(""" | Model  | Company  | Url  | Criteria              |    Rating
1| Mode11 | Company1 | Url1 |[Criteria1, Criteria2] | [Rating1 , Rating2]
2| Mode12 | Company2 | Url2 |[Criteria4, Criteria5] | [Rating4, Rating5]""")
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(dfstr, sep='|')
df.columns = ['Model','Company','Url','Criteria','Rating'] # no whitespace


def slist(listish): # list-without-quotes is kind of a pain
    return listish.strip(' []').split(', ')

def row2df(oldrow): # make a little sub-DataFrame for each row 
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(zip(slist(row[1].Criteria),slist(row[1].Rating)))
    for val in ['Model','Company','Url']:
        tmp[val] = row[1][val]
    return tmp


outdf = pd.concat([row2df(row) for row in df.iterrows()]) # and stick them together
outdf.index = outdf[0] # index on the Criteria
outdf.drop(0, axis=1,inplace=True) 
outdf.columns = ['Rating','Model','Company','Url'] # tidy up the names
print(outdf)
```

Comment: cool. if  you consider the question answered, there's a checkmark-clicking thing near the upper left of the answer to say so. (Also gives me some stackoverflow points.)

Comment: says i Vote Up requires 15 reputation. I will vote up your answer once I get 15 reputation.  you really saved me a lot of time. Thanks

Comment: Since you asked the question, I think you get to say that this *is* an answer to it -- the checkmark is under the Vote Down arrow.  (Welcome to StackOverflow, too.)